# Issues with www vs non www domains

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to make updates to a site hosted at siteground.com.  When I update the file and upload it to the server if I go to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) I do not see the changes but if I go to mysite.com I do.

If anyone can explain to me how this is happening I would greatly appreciate it..  I have also tried editing the .htaccess file but the redirect will not work.  Here is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: A few times.  I don't know why this only seems to happen with this site on sitegrouind.

Comment: This clearly sounds like a caching issue, _unless_ you actually doubled your content on the server side. So maybe you cleared the wrong cache? The wrong time period? I suggest you test, as it generally is advisable, using a fresh anonymous browser window. Also consider if there is some proxy between you and your server which would cache content.

Comment: About that redirection rule not working: although it certainly contains issues the rule itself should work. If it does not then it probably won't get applied at all. Either you implemented it at the wrong location in the file system or the interpretation of such distributed configuration files is not enabled or the http server cannot read that file. You can probably find some hints in your http server's error log file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try using Cloudflare and them "redirects rules" in there, if the problem is cache using cloudflare in your domain is another layer and wont have problem with cache. In my opinion.